# Matrix operation errors in sympy

Tags: python, sympy

I am trying to write a sympy script, but facing problems at L1,L2. Any help is welcome.

At L1, I am trying to substitute values in matrix multiplication expression in earlier line. Can't I substitute in matrix object?

At L2, I am trying to evaluate value of the substitution in floating point numbers, but not getting it. Why  eval() is not giving floating point value?

```
from sympy import *
init_printing()
x, x1, x2, x3 = symbols ('x x1 x2 x3')
N1 = ((x-x2)*(x-x3))/( (x1-x2) * (x1-x3) )
N2 = ((x-x1)*(x-x3))/( (x2-x1) * (x2-x3) )
N = Matrix([ [N1,N2] ] )
expr1 = N*Transpose(N)
print expr1.subs([ (x1,0.0), (x2,2.5), (x3,5) ]) #L1
N1.evalf (subs={x1:0.0, x2:2.5, x3:5}) #L2
```

EDIT:

After one answer, I am putting some extra lines of code. Lines `L3,L4, are not working. At L3,L4, I am trying to integrate f1, which is a matrix, and row of that matrix. But failing in both cases. How to integrate a matrix in sympy? Is it supported?

```
from sympy import *
init_printing()
x, x1, x2, x3 = symbols ('x x1 x2 x3')
N1 = ((x-x2)*(x-x3))/( (x1-x2) * (x1-x3) )
N2 = ((x-x1)*(x-x3))/( (x2-x1) * (x2-x3) )
N = Matrix([ [N1,N2] ] )
expr1 = N*Transpose(N)
print expr1.subs([ (x1,0.0), (x2,2.5), (x3,5) ]) #L1
N1s=N1.subs( [ (x1,0.0), (x2,2.5), (x3,5) ])
N2s=N2.subs( [ (x1,0.0), (x2,2.5), (x3,5) ])
Ns = Matrix([ [N1s,N2s] ] )
f1 = Ns*x**3
f2 = integrate(f1,(x,0,5)) #L3
f2 = integrate(f1.row(1),(x,0,5)) #L4
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first line works for me. Make sure you are using the latest version of SymPy (1.0 at the time of this writing).

The second line does not work because `evalf(subs={...})` doesn't work unless you substitute all the variables in an expression. See https://github.com/sympy/sympy/issues/6974. If you only want to substitute some of the variables, just use `subs`.

Comment: Thanks very much for answer. Can you also comment about `L3,L4`?

Comment: @vfg4341 it would be better to ask a new question for that

Comment: asked new question here. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42033042/error-in-operations-on-matrices-in-sympy